# upper- to lower-case on first column only in bash

Tags: bash

How do I change in bash only the first column into lower case?
for example:
ABC|DEF|GHI
to
abc|DEF|GHI

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`echo "ABC|DEF|GHI" | sed 's/\([A-Z]*\)\|/\L\1/'`

outputs:

`abc|DEF|GHI`

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F"|" '{l = $0; sub($1, "", l); print tolower($1) l}' yourFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Look Ma, no *sed*!

```
e="ABC|DEF|GHI"
prefix=${e%%|*}
postfix=${e#*|}
echo ${prefix,,}"|"${postfix}
```

Result:

```
abc|DEF|GHI
```

- `${e%%|*}` removes everything matching |* from the end
- `${e%|*}` removes one match from the end
- `${e##*|}` removes everything matching *| from the beginning
- `${e#*|}` removes one match *| from the beginning
- `${prefix,,}` produces lowercase
- `${prefix^^}` produces uppercase

See `man bash`, section `Parameter expansion` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "ABC|DEF|GHI" | sed 's/[^|]*/\L&/'
abc|DEF|GHI
```